# Php add 24 htrs to current unix time

Tags: php, unix

Am saving date and time in php and having a condition that checks if the time minus 24 hours is less than zero

This is how i have tried

```
$time_registed=1500373706;
$timeafter24hrs = $time_registed + //am stuck here 

if($timeafter24hrs - time() < 0){

    //do stuff since its after 24 hrs
 }
```

How do i add 24 hrs to the unix time?

Comment: When would this ever be true? For example: `today - 24hrs = same time yesterday`. It would never be `< 0`.

Comment: In my situation am checking if the time the item was registed has passed 24 hrs which is logically possible to check if time registered plus 24 hrs minus current time is less than zero as time in unix increases as seconds progresses hence i expect current time will be greater than time registered

Comment: @Tigger time() essentially gives the current time in seconds since epoch. Hence, `today - 24hrs` is a very different time from today, essentially, 24*60*60 less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$time_registed = 1500373706; // assuming this value is dynamic

if ((time() - $time_registed) > 86400) {
    echo 'More than 24hrs ago';
} else {
    echo 'Less than 24hrs ago';
}
```

Edit: Please see change. There was an error and simplified a little.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeafter24hrs = $time_registered + 24*60*60;
```

I assume $time_registered is the time from where you want to add 24 hours.